# How to achieve "e.target.value" in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i wanna access button value in react native, in pure javascript it look like :

```
const checkingStuff = (e) => console.log(e.target.value)

<button onclick={checkingStuff} > this is the value </button>.
```

how to achieve the same thing in react native?

edit : please answer in react native, not react js, because

```
<Button
onPress={checkingStuff}
title='lalala123'/>
```

give me 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import Button from react-native, this can be a solution for you

```
<Button title='here is your button text' onPress={(e)=>console.log(e._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children[0].props.children)}/>
```

But if you import Button from other source, or if this does not bring the exact value to this, then you can go upto `e._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children` then check your button text item position and get it in your own way.

Comment: But in real app you should handle it with different mechanism, that will help you to use this value anywhere any purpose; say, you can declare a value for your button first, then use it, mix it, modify it, or update it for your button also for other places wherever necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know excatly what you try to achieve, however you should access the event directly in the input instead of the button. For TextInput in React Native, the changed text is passed as a single string argument to the callback handler.

You can try this

```
const [text, onChangeText] = useState("")
const onPress = () => {
   console.log(text)
}

return (
    <>
        <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={onChangeText}>
        <Button onPress={onPress}/>
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`event handlers` give you inherent access to the `event` through the function.  Unless specifically setting state within the DOM, there's no need to do an inline arrow function.  You can simply reference the function like so:

```
const checkingStuff = (e) => { console.log(e.target.value) }

<button onClick={checkingStuff} > Set state and add your {value} like so </button>
```

Comment: it is reactjs answer sir, can u answer this in react native way?

Comment: From what I have gathered, the same approach should work on React Native.  They give an example on how to use ````button```` here: https://reactnative-examples.com/example-of-set-onpress-onclick-on-text-in-react-native/

Answer (score 1):

I mostly used below methods:

1. In the TextInput Itself.

   ```
    <TextInput
    style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
    onChangeText={text => console.log(text);
    value={value}
    />
   ```
2. If using Class in react-native.

   ```
    <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
           placeholder = "Password"
           placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
           autoCapitalize = "none"
           onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}/>
   ```

And this.handlePassword is:

```
 handlePassword = (text) => {
  this.setState({ password: text })
 }
```

Of if you are using functional Component:

```
const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("");
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    value={text}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this:

```
const checkingStuff = (e) => console.log(e.target.value)

<button onclick={(e) => checkingStuff(e)} > this is the value </button>
```

Comment: it is reactjs answer sir, can u answer this in react native way?